# Windows Phone 7 - How to Update UI From while Loop?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, user-interface, windows-phone

How would I update the UI in my Windows Phone app from a while, foreach, for, etc loop?

Comment: the same way as without while, foreach, for, etc loop. What is the problem?

Comment: The user interface freezes during the loop, to be more specific I am looking for a way to add a large number of items to a list box during the while loop I use to read a text file, so they appear one by one instead of after a delay of 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: You might try `UpdateLayout()` within each iteration, but agree with Scada's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using additional thread for this?

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => ReadFile(/*params*/));
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void ReadFile(/*params*/)
        {   
            while(/*condition*/)
            {
                /* READ FILE */

                //send task to UI thread to add object to list box
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => listBox1.Items.Add("YOUR OBJECT"));
            }
        }
```

Long term action is happening in non-UI thread, what makes that UI thread doesn`t get frozen. In every loop iteration, non-UI Thread sends action via Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to UI thread to add new object to listbox.